# Automated URL Hyperlink creation

Tags: sed, url

I have a document full of URL's that I need to turn into hyperlinks. I have no clue where to begin.

My file looks like this but longer:

```
 http://somesite1.html
 http://somesiteAD.html
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
 <a href="http://somesite1.html">http://somesite1.html</a>
 <a href="http://somesiteAD.html">http://somesiteAD.html</a>
```

Recommendations on how to accomplish this?

Comment: `sed -e 's|.*|<a href="&">&</a>|'`

Comment: @RakeshSharma Thank you, that was a huge help and it resolved my problem.   My new line reads: grep -lr -Fiw 'KeyWord' * | sed -e 's|.*|<li><a href="http://&">&</a></li>|'  >>  temp.html

Answer (score 1):

If your file only contains lines with URLs:

```
awk '{print "<a href=\""$1"\">"$1"</a>"}' <urls >hyperlinks
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex might be helpful:

```
 s/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(:[0-9]+)?|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/<a href="$1">$1</a>/g
```

But I advise you to look online yourself for more regexes that match URLs, for your specific case.